# Using a Shader Node Mask to Slice Geometry or Create Spline

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes, masking

Is there any way to use my shader nodes procedural mask to slice another plane?

I have a procedural texture that makes different leaves in shader nodes on a plane.
I don't want to have to reimplement this in geometry nodes and have to link the parameters, so I was thinking this would be an easier solution for cutting out the leaf and the vein structure.

The edge mask.

[image]

The vein structure.

[image]

To be clear I know I can use a grid to delete vertices outside my image as in this video.
[Turn 2D Images Into 3D Objects In Blender 3.2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yHrHn0FxXw)
However the end result won't follow the outside of my mask exactly.
I suppose I'm really looking to turn this into a curve I can fill.

I can import my image into Inkscape and stroke a path that way but I really wish there was a workflow that remained in Blender.

FINAL EDIT:
I decided that all the work was probably not worth it. I baked my original shader to another subdivided plane and used the leaf outline mask to control my transparency.

The final plane.

[image]

My node setup.

[image]

The final result.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to do this procedurally, or is a one time operation like "[Trace Image to Grease Pencil](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/object/trace_image.html)" enough?

Comment: I'm really just trying to streamline the process. I'll be making 4 or 5 different leaves for just the first plant I'm starting. Then I'm manually damaging them to get some more mileage out of each leaf and then I'll have to bake my textures and make vertex groups for the cloth simulation. I'd like to automate the geometry in lock step with the shader to save the repetition and move onto the artistic portion.

Comment: I decided baking my texture to a subdivided plane and controlling the alpha with my leaf mask was more than acceptable. I'll post an image and explanation in the original question explaining.